Has anyone ever studied which proof types are feasible for which theorems in mathematics? If not, why not?
For instance, when asked to prove that sqrt(2) is irrational, we go straight for the proof by contradiction where we assume it’s equal to a/b in lowest terms and end up with a and b not being in lowest terms. On the other hand, the proof of some other theorem might always be done directly, or happen to be feasible using multiple proof types. If it hasn't already been done, could studying which proof types are feasible for which theorems in mathematics ever have any practical use, or would this just not be useful information to look into?

This will get better answers on math SE

There's something to be said for direct proofs for irrationality of sqrt(2)) See
.

"√2 is irrational" is a negative statement, so the only way to prove it is by assuming that √2 is rational and deriving a contradiction. This is not a proof by contradiction in the sense of constructive mathematics.

Welcome! I would say you might want to start by reading the SEP's article on Proof Theory. Then, once you get a good idea, take a look at Model Theory. The former is about immediately about proofs, and the latter is about understanding proofs as linguistic entities within a Tarskian framework of truth-conditional semantics.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_mathematics

echoing @NaïmFavier this is better called a proof by negation.  for proofs that rely on contradiction, see constructive/intuitonistic math vs classical.

Andrej Bauer has written a post describing the difference between proof of negation and proof by contradiction.

All already proved or provable math theorems have been or will be proved as computably enumerable (ce, or re) sets, ergo insofar as the proof steps or sequents are of the types of correct, normalized, subformulaed and cut appropriately, they're not useful, not to mention the unprovable Godel like statements...

Typically, constructive proofs are better than nonconstructive ones, because it is nice to be shown a solution rather than told that there is one but we don't know what it looks like. So, many people prefer direct proofs to indirect ones that rely on proof by contradiction. But it also depends on your approach to the concept of mathematical truth. For the classical logician, the difference ultimately is not important. For the intuitionist, nonconstructive proofs are not legitimate.

@Bumble  IMO the difference is deeper than that and the real trouble comes with the very logic: e.g. that "if you don't see that it is not raining, you can conclude that it is raining"...

@JulioDiEgidio If the question is asking about logical pluralism, I agree. There are many logics and they have different proof systems. However, the question asks specifically about mathematical theorems, so it may be that we are meant to hold the choice of logic constant.

@Bumble  I don't see a distinction there: classical mathematics is built on classical logic principles, and I am trying to point out that "a non-constructive (namely, classical) proof doesn't give us a witness" is the least of the problems with classical logic and mathematics...

@JulioDiEgidio In that case, I'm interested to know what you think are the more serious problems with classical logic and mathematics. Maybe a subject for another question.

@Bumble  "if you don't see that it is not raining, you can conclude that it is raining": if you don't see how problematic that is, yes, maybe we should talk about it sooner than later (no kidding): my understanding is that these are the days we might build something better, or never again.  I won't add more in these comments.

P.S. I won't add more... except for mentioning that the Drinker's Paradox is prototypical of the actual underlying assumptions: I have an analysis and a formalization in Coq but I have not yet published it, will post a link at the first occasion when I do.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@user509184: I have expanded on your comment in my answer. =)

I think it’s worth pointing out before going all the way down to the foundational level, most theorems belong to certain archetypes, which have common proof approaches within their foundations. Want to prove a theorem with form A v B, prove A or B individually (in classical math), want to prove A iff B, one way is to prove A -> B and B -> A. This is taught very early on and often there are appendices of several dozen of these techniques. It’s one way to understand the OP’s question.

@asdf555: Have you understood my answer?

As pointed out by user509184 in a comment, reverse mathematics is exactly the study of which foundational systems can prove a theorem of interest. Historically, this has focused on systems of arithmetic, in particular systems weaker than PA and systems stronger than PA but not going beyond HOA (higher-order arithmetic). For some philosophical remarks on this, read this post. Note that the "Big Five Systems" here are all classical systems, due to the undeniable extent of real-world applications of (classical) real analysis, which also explains why a lot of the theorems investigated in reverse mathematics are related to logic or real analysis. In particular, it has been consensus among expert logicians for a long time that PA actually holds a special place; it can be conservatively extended to a system called ACA0 that so far is capable of proving correctness of every application of mathematics to the real world (excluding insubstantial consequences of the incompleteness theorems such as the fact that a program searching for a PA-proof of "0=1" will never halt).
It may not be obvious how the above answers your question, but in fact it has very important implications for applied mathematics. It implies that we ought to expect to be able to prove any practically useful real-world fact that can be mathematically stated using ACA0.
Now you also asked about proof techniques. Firstly you have a misconception about the proof that √2 is irrational; by definition of "irrational" you have no choice but to prove a contradiction under the assumption that √2 is rational! Such analysis of proof techniques can be done in some other cases too. But for reasons related to the incompleteness theorem, it is not possible to systematically determine whether a statement can be proven or not. And even if a statement is guaranteed to be provable, it is usually also hard to efficiently find a proof. For example, every first-order statement about ⟨ℝ,0,1,+,·,<⟩ can be either proven or disproven within the FOL theory RCF, but the shortest proof length may be doubly-exponential in the length of the statement! So there is a fundamental limit to the efficiency of proofs or disproofs of first-order statements about real numbers.
See also this post about why mathematics in general is inherently hard, which also implies hardness of figuring out which proof techniques/tactics are useful for a given theorem. Note that one must be careful in talking about known provable statements, because the trivial algorithmic procedure that searches through all proofs in length-lexicographic order will find a proof if it exists.
In an orthogonal direction, there is the BHK interpretation for IFOL (intuitionistic FOL), which implies that any theorem that cannot be witnessed by a computable function necessarily cannot be proven within IFOL from any axioms that have computable witness functions. And since the only difference between IFOL and FOL (in suitable axiomatizations) is either ¬¬-elimination or LEM, you know immediately that to prove these theorems you have to use one of these.
